# How to prevent datepicker trigger event when I manually set date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 events

1. datepicker that will alert text when user select date
2. button that will set date to today when click

I don't want to alert "date change" when user click a button,
please check my code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
        alert('date change');
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
       setTodayDate(); // when click I don't want this to trigger datepicker event
    });

  function setTodayDate(){
     var currentDate = new Date();
     $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", currentDate); 

  }

});
```

Thank you

Comment: But doesn't `setTodayDate()` change the date so will trigger `changeDate`?

Comment: Are you using a plugin of some sort? Do you have access to the datepicker function? Maybe you can change it to allow a parameter to prevent the event from firing.

Comment: setTodayDate function update the date that's why it triggers the changeDate function but if you do not want to alert then you can manage using some flag.

Comment: Oh yes I should do some flag Thank you